# C++ if/else statements not properly outputting

Tags: c++, if-statement

currently, I am having an issue with this if/else statement. this is the source here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string firstname, secondname;
    const int A_SCORE = 90;
    const int B_SCORE = 80;
    const int C_SCORE = 70;
    const int D_SCORE = 60;

    int testscore1;
    int testscore2;
    int testscore3;
    int testscore4;
    int testscore5;
    int testscore6;
    int testscore7;
    int testscore8;
    int testscore9;
    int testscore10;

    cout << "Enter your 10 scores and I will average\n"
        << "the total score, and assign letter grades" << endl;

    cin >> testscore1;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore2;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore3;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore4;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore5;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore6;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore7;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore8;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore9;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> testscore10;
    cin.ignore();

    int sum = testscore1 + testscore2 + testscore3 + testscore4 + testscore5 + testscore6 + testscore7 + testscore8 + testscore9 + testscore10;
    int average = sum / 10;

    if (average == 90);
    {
        cout << "your average is an A.";
    }

    else if (average == 80);
    {
        cout << "you have an average of a B.";
    }

    else if (average == 70);
    {
        cout << "you have an average of a C.";
    }

    else  (average == 60);
    {
        cout << "your average is a D.":
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

what the goal of this homework assignment is, is to input 10 numerical grades and have an average print out to screen with a letter grade based on average of the 10 grades. I no matter what I input, I always get 'your grade is an A. I have went over my notes ad well as looking to goodle/StackOverflow for what could be wrong. I also get compile errors too, which I cannot figure out. If someone could give me any ideas on what could be causing the issue, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried outputting the values of `sum` and `average` to `cout` before your if-else chain?

Comment: no change at all. does not even display average or sum at all.

Comment: All your `if` statements have erroneous semi-colons after them.

Comment: When you have a series of variables which differ in name by only a number, this suggests you should use an array and for loop instead.

Comment: All of your `cin.ignore()` are redundant; reading an integer ignores whitespace anyway

Comment: This code isn't close to compiling so how are you getting "your grade is an A" ?

Comment: removed all cin.ignore()s

we havent went over loops or arrays yet

it compiles with errors, and that is the result it always gives me

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolons after the if statements and instead of checking for the values to be exactly 90/80/70 try something like this:

```
if(average >= 90)
{
//print
}
```

If you want more accurate results try using floats instead of integers.

Comment: and I just saw something I didnt notice...thanks to the code PAul Rooney posted!

Answer (score 1):

Your if-statements should take the form of `if(average >= 90, 80, etc...)`.

Also, what are your errors?

EDIT:

```
if (average >= 90)
{
    cout << "your average is an A.";
}

else if (average >= 80)
{
    cout << "you have an average of a B.";
}

else if (average >= 70)
{
    cout << "you have an average of a C.";
}

else if(average >= 60)
{
    cout << "your average is a D.";
}
else
{
    cout << "your average is an F.";
}

return 0;
```

You needed to remove all of the semicolons, one colon, change your relational operator from `==` to `>=`, and add an extra else to catch anything below 60.

Comment: C4390 ';' : empty controlled statementfound;is this the intent?

Comment: and c2181: Illegal else without matching if

Comment: Alright. I read that you removed all of the erroneous semicolons. Did doing that get rid of those errors? It looks like it should have.

Comment: unfortunately it did not

Answer (score 1):

If..else statements are conditional. You need to provide the accurate conditions to get the results that you expect.
Try:

```css
if (average >= A_SCORE)
{
    cout << "your average is an A.";
}

else if (average >= B_SCORE)
{
    cout << "you have an average of a B.";
}

else if (average >= C_SCORE)
{
    cout << "you have an average of a C.";
}

else if(average >= D_SCORE)
{
    cout << "your average is a D.";
}
else
{
    cout << "your average is an F.";
}

system("pause);
```